# How to setup SQL Server database to allow multiple users to connect via C# App?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, connection

I have created an Autodesk Plugin and I want to include a licensing system so that you can only use the plugin if you have entered a valid license. If a user installs the plugin on their machine and enters a valid license key, how can I have it check the SQL database (which is on another computer) for that license key?

I have setup the SQL database to run locally but because I am quite new to SQL I am not so sure on the exact steps to configure the database to be accessed outside of the local computer.

I have tried following the steps provided in the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-1-connecting-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

But when I try to follow the steps for 'Authorising Additional Connections' I attempt to try and create a new user, Test, using my computers name as the domain, My-Computer's-Name and it says:
"Windows NT user or group "My-Computer's-Name\Test"" not found.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Is the database local or on a server? You stated it is both in your question.

Comment: You need to setup a User Group Account on both local and remote machines.  Then set database in SQL Server to use a Group Account.  And then put users into the group.  This way you can use Windows Credential when login.  The connection string in c# would have Integrated Security=true which will use the users login as the credentials (the group account) for the database.

Answer (score 0):

You have two easy choices:

1. If your SQL Server has SQL Server and Windows authentication, you
   can create just SQL login account;
2. When you are trying to use Windows authentication try to use "Search" button to verify that account you are trying to use exists and visible by SQL Server.

Comment: SQL Server has the possibility to use SQL Server login, if I use this instead and change to C# code will that allow the application to access the database after it has been installed on another computer?

Comment: It should. It is easy, but it is not the best practice though. If you want to be a good developer, try to use Windows Groups instead. Then you will have less problems in the future.

Comment: Thank you, Slava. I will take a look into using Windows Groups!

Comment: Slava, I have spent today looking into Windows Groups and Active Directory. Our company is small and does not use Active Directory so I don't believe this is a valid option for what I want to do. If I want users across multiple companies to be able to use my application and enter a license key and successfully allow the code to connect to the SQL Server database to check and see if that key is valid, is it possible to achieve this with SQL Server logins?

Comment: You can use SQL Server Logins. Also, make sure SQL Server is visible by remote clients. If you use Express, it is local by default.